# Trying to create <li> element with JavaScript, but it disappears

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make an li element using JavaScript. I was taught that this will work but it is not. When I click the submit button what I wrote in the text field appears, then disappears very quickly. What should I do?

```js
function addLi () {
    var x = document.createElement("LI");
    var t = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('text').value);
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("elements").appendChild(x);
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <title>ToDoList</title>
        <script src="todolist.js"></script>
    <header>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form onSubmit="addLi();">
                <input type="text" value="Type here!" id="text">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
            <ol id="elements">
            </ol>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Try adding a `return false; ` at the end of your function. Your `form` is probably being submitted. The snippet of your question works, I think it is because the form isn't being submitted.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: That alone doesn't help. But the reason is correct.

Comment: @FelixKling I tried a suggestion w/o changing the code, but a `event.preventDefault()` would be more accurate.

Comment: The default action of the submit event is to submit the form. That involves an HTTP request to a page and loading that page. If you don't want this to happen, you have to **prevent** the default action.

Comment: event.preventDefault()?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: `return false;` works but only if the inline event handler is changed to `return addLi();`.

Comment: @FelixKling sure, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @Felix said is true. Your `submit` button is submitting the `form`, which opens a request reloading the page. This is the default behaviour. You have to *cancel*(aka *prevent*) this behaviour in order to get your function to work:

1. You can add a `return` statement to your `onSubmit` event in the `form` element:

   ```
   <form onSubmit="return addLi();">
   ```

   And then `return false;` at the end of your function.

   [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ug6ep9cg/)
2. You can pass the current `event` to the handler and [*prevent*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) it to work as expected:

   ```
   <form onSubmit="addLi(event);">
   ```

   Then add `event.preventDefault();` at the end of your function.

   [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ug6ep9cg/1/)
3. You can also get rid of the `submit` and use a `button`, which by default doesn't submits the `form`:

   ```
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="addLi()" />
   ```

   [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ug6ep9cg/2/)

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` is the safest action to take.  See this article: https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

Comment: I used your first suggestion and it worked. I'm happy that it works but I don't quite understand why it works now. Can you explain why? :)

Comment: @AndreiSimedre If you know how a `form` work you should understand by the explanation in the beginning of the answer. Do you know how it works?

Comment: @AndreiSimedre Its ok. I mean, if you still don't know how a `form` works, you should go after it, or it will be confuse, indeed.

Comment: @AndreiSimedre remeber to [accept the answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).